# Error in return function

Tags: mysql

I apologise if this seems very vague but I'm not sure how else to word it.
I developed a function that if the day is either Saturday or Sunday, anticipates or postpones the payment of taxes. The following code:

```
DELIMITER $
create function ajustavencimento (ano int, mes int, imposto char(6)) returns varchar(10) 
begin
  declare vencimento datetime;
  declare dia int;
  declare diaPIS int;
  declare ajustePIS varchar(50);

  if (mes = 12) then
  begin
    set mes = 1;
    set ano = ano + 1;
  end; else
  begin
    set mes = mes + 1;
  end;
  end if;    

  if (imposto = 'PIS') then
  begin
    select pisvencimento into diaPIs from pis; 
    select pisajuste into ajustePIS from pis; 
    set vencimento = cast(concat(cast(ano as char(4)),'-',cast(mes as char(2)),'-',cast(diaPIS as char(2))) as datetime);

    set dia = date_format(vencimento,'%w');
    if(dia = 0) then 
    begin
      if (ajustePIS = 'Antecepiar') then
        set vencimento = date_sub(vencimento, interval 2 day);
      end if;
      if (ajustePIS = 'Adiar') then
        set vencimento = date_add(vencimento, interval 1 day);
      end if;              
    end;
    end if;

    if(dia = 6) then 
    begin
      if (ajustePIS = 'Antecepiar') then
        set vencimento = date_sub(vencimento, interval 1 day);
      end if;
      if (ajustePIS = 'Adiar') then
        set vencimento = date_add(vencimento, interval 2 day);
      end if;              
    end;
    end if;
  end;
  end if;    
  return date_format(vencimento,'%d/%m/%Y');
end
```

The function always returns the date

```
25/02/2013 - OK
25/03/2013 - OK
25/04/2013 - OK
25/05/2013 - NOT (MUST RETURN 27/05/2013)
25/06/2013 - OK
```

Comment: What are the values of pisvencimento  & pisajuste?  e.g. what is in pis?  Can you add some comments in English explaining what different parts of the code are trying to do?   What are the values of all the parameters you are calling the function with?

Comment: Instead of `date_format(vencimento, '%w')`, you can use `dayofweek(vencimento)`. Just remember that it uses Sunday=1, not 0.

Comment: `25/05/2013` is a Saturday. Your function only adjust for Sunday.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, 
pisvencimento = day of the month chosen for the payment of tax (25);
ajustePIS = information to postpone or advance payment ( "anticipates" or "delay").
PIS = Tax name in Brazil.

Comment: the problem could well be in table pis, an inconsistency  with pisvencimento and/or pisajuste; have you checked that the May/2013 row is correct in this table?